# Flash version across browsers

Tags: flash

This may seem like an obvious question but I can't find an answer..

Is the flash version installed on, say IE, on a single computer the same version on other browsers installed on that same computer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE uses an ActiveX control for its flash implementation whereas most other browsers use a Mozilla/Netscape plugin thing.  Chrome seems to have its own implementation as well.  So it is totally possible to have multiple versions of flash installed on a computer being used by different browsers.